# Jquery menu - toggle sub-menu area and css state change on parent menu button

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

Apologies if this is very easy or I've missed the point...

From searching stackoverflow, I've combined two very helpful segments of code, but I have a weird outcome.

I have a menu with 3 parent buttons - each time one of those is clicked, I'd like it to open a sub-nav box and change the css state of the parent menu item. I'd like this to then toggle back on the next click or when another parent menu item is clicked.

What I have below toggles the sub-nav box open/closed, but toggles non-clicked parent menu itmes (the opposite of what I want!). I *think* I'm close but yet so far far away! Here's what I have:

jquery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".shownavsection").click(function () {
var cls = this.className.match(/link1|link2|link3/),
    box = $(".section."+cls[0]);

// slideUp() on all .countries elements
$(".section").not(box).slideUp();

box.slideToggle();   

$(".arr").not($(this)).toggleClass("on");
;
return false;


});
});//]]>
```

CSS

```
li{
list-style-type:none; list-style-position:inside}

a.arr:link, a.arr:visited 
{ 
width:160px; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; float:left;
font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:12px;
background-color: #FFF; 
height:21px; display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#999999;
padding:5px 0px 0px 10px
}

 a.arr:hover
 {
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
 font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;color:#999999 
}

.on {
background: #000 !important;
}
.mm {
border:1px solid #013b5d;
border-top: 1px solid #fff;
width: 960px;
height:auto;
padding:10px 5px 20px 5px;
display:none;
margin-top:10px;
clear: both;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 10px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 10px #888;
box-shadow: 0 8px 10px #888;    

font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>

<li><a href="#" class="shownavsection link1 arr"> link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="shownavsection link2 arr"> link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="shownavsection link3 arr"> link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="section link1 mm cf">1</div>
<div class="section link2 mm cf">2</div>
<div class="section link3 mm cf">3</div>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Put it in a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) and maybe we can fix it for you.

Comment: Cheers Jeff  - not signed up to that before - back in a few mins. Appreciated.

Comment: Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/eL4yvtod/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Below Code** - you have to use [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

**[Working - JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/juej84g3/)**

```
$(window).load(function(){    
    $(".shownavsection").click(function () {
    var cls = this.className.match(/link1|link2|link3/),
        box = $(".section."+cls[0]);
        $(".shownavsection").not(this).removeClass("on"); // UPDATED LINE
        $(this).toggleClass("on");                      // UPDATED LINE
        $(".section").not(box).slideUp();
        box.slideToggle();   
        return false;
    });
});
```

<strike>**[Click here to - Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/juej84g3/)**</strike>

**Updated Answer : - ** see the above code **"UPDATED LINE"** for your second question related - if user **click twice** in a row- it will remove `"on"` clss from link.

[See the Updates **JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/juej84g3/1/)

Comment: Prog thank you very much. There's one tiny thing that I should have mentioned - is it possible, after clicking 'link 1' twice in a row, to remove the 'on' class? If not thank you anyway, you gem! How do I clcik 'accept'? Can't see the button - apologies.

Comment: @Huckerby - Sure, here you go for your solution - if user click twice in a row on same `link` - See the updated answer above.

Comment: Prog - thanks - you've really sorted me out there - can I 'buy you a beer'!?

Comment: @Huckerby - you will get the `accept` button right below to the `up` and `down`  vote button - `accept` it - it will helps other to find correct solution